# goback in webview flutter by back button device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, flutter-dependencies

I have 4 bottomNavigationBar that each one has a webview.
but when tap in a one bottomNavigationBar and select a section in webview page, **I can't back to previous page in webview by button back device.**

**I want back in webview just by back button device.**

it is now when the press back button exit the app.
but I use double_back_to_close_app.dart to exit the app.

**the home class :**

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart'; 
import 'package:fancy_bar/fancy_bar.dart';
import 'placeholder_widget.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    MyPlaceholderWidget('https://googel.com'),
    MyPlaceholderWidget('https://googel.com'),
    MyPlaceholderWidget('https://googel.com'),
    MyPlaceholderWidget('https://googel.com')
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0),
        child: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
          elevation: 0.0,
        )
      ),
    body: DoubleBackToCloseApp(
        child:  _children[_currentIndex],
        snackBar: const SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              'برای خروج دو بار کلیک کنید',
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Shabnam"),
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),

        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: FancyBottomBar(
        onItemSelected: onTabTapped,
        selectedIndex: _currentIndex, // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
        items: [
            FancyItem(
              textColor:  Colors.green,
              title: 'حساب',
              icon: Icon(
                LineIcons.user,
                size: 29,
              ),
            ),
            FancyItem(
              textColor:  Colors.green,
              title: 'وبلاگ',
              icon: Icon(
                LineIcons.file_text,
                size: 27,
              ),            
            ),
            FancyItem(
              textColor:  Colors.green,
              title: 'سبد خرید',
              icon: Icon(
                LineIcons.shopping_cart,
                size: 31,
              ),  
            ),
            FancyItem(
              textColor:  Colors.green,
              title: 'صفحه اصلی',
              icon: Icon(
                LineIcons.home,
                size: 28,
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

**and the webview class in placeholder_widget.dart:**

```
WebViewController controller;

class MyPlaceholderWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  var url = 'https://www.mayehtaj.ir'  ;
  final key = UniqueKey();

  MyPlaceholderWidget(String url){
    this.url = url ;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return WebView(
        key: key,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        initialUrl: url,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController){
          controller = webViewController;
      });

   }
  }
```

**How to detect press back button device and go back to previous page in one webview ?**

thank you for help !

Answer (score 6):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can wrap `Scaffold` with `WillPopScope` 
When user click `device back button`, you can execute `WebView Controller goback`

code snippet onwillpop

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
          // This drop down menu demonstrates that Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.
          actions: <Widget>[
            NavigationControls(_controller.future),
            SampleMenu(_controller.future),
          ],
        ),
```

code snippet for exit app

```
WebViewController controllerGlobal;

Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
  if (await controllerGlobal.canGoBack()) {
    print("onwill goback");
    controllerGlobal.goBack();
  } else {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
    );
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: WebViewExample()));

const String kNavigationExamplePage = '''
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><title>Navigation Delegate Example</title></head>
<body>
<p>
The navigation delegate is set to block navigation to the youtube website.
</p>
<ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">https://www.youtube.com/</a></ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a></ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.google.com/">https://nodejs.org/en</a></ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
''';

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewExampleState createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

WebViewController controllerGlobal;

Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
  if (await controllerGlobal.canGoBack()) {
    print("onwill goback");
    controllerGlobal.goBack();
  } else {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
    );
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
  Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
          // This drop down menu demonstrates that Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.
          actions: <Widget>[
            NavigationControls(_controller.future),
            SampleMenu(_controller.future),
          ],
        ),
        // We're using a Builder here so we have a context that is below the Scaffold
        // to allow calling Scaffold.of(context) so we can show a snackbar.
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            // TODO(iskakaushik): Remove this when collection literals makes it to stable.
            // ignore: prefer_collection_literals
            javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
              _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
            ].toSet(),
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
              if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                print('blocking navigation to $request}');
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              }
              if (request.url.startsWith('https://flutter.dev/docs')) {
                print('blocking navigation to $request}');
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              }
              print('allowing navigation to $request');
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            },
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              print('Page finished loading: $url');
            },
          );
        }),
        floatingActionButton: favoriteButton(),
      ),
    );
  }

  JavascriptChannel _toasterJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
    return JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget favoriteButton() {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
          if (controller.hasData) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final String url = await controller.data.currentUrl();
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Favorited $url')),
                );
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
}

enum MenuOptions {
  showUserAgent,
  listCookies,
  clearCookies,
  addToCache,
  listCache,
  clearCache,
  navigationDelegate,
}

class SampleMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  SampleMenu(this.controller);

  final Future<WebViewController> controller;
  final CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: controller,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
        return PopupMenuButton<MenuOptions>(
          onSelected: (MenuOptions value) {
            switch (value) {
              case MenuOptions.showUserAgent:
                _onShowUserAgent(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.listCookies:
                _onListCookies(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.clearCookies:
                _onClearCookies(context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.addToCache:
                _onAddToCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.listCache:
                _onListCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.clearCache:
                _onClearCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.navigationDelegate:
                _onNavigationDelegateExample(controller.data, context);
                break;
            }
          },
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>>[
            PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.showUserAgent,
              child: const Text('Show user agent'),
              enabled: controller.hasData,
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.listCookies,
              child: Text('List cookies'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.clearCookies,
              child: Text('Clear cookies'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.addToCache,
              child: Text('Add to cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.listCache,
              child: Text('List cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.clearCache,
              child: Text('Clear cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.navigationDelegate,
              child: Text('Navigation Delegate example'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _onShowUserAgent(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    // Send a message with the user agent string to the Toaster JavaScript channel we registered
    // with the WebView.
    controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'Toaster.postMessage("User Agent: " + navigator.userAgent);');
  }

  void _onListCookies(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String cookies =
    await controller.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('Cookies:'),
          _getCookieList(cookies),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  void _onAddToCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'caches.open("test_caches_entry"); localStorage["test_localStorage"] = "dummy_entry";');
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Added a test entry to cache.'),
    ));
  }

  void _onListCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.evaluateJavascript('caches.keys()'
        '.then((cacheKeys) => JSON.stringify({"cacheKeys" : cacheKeys, "localStorage" : localStorage}))'
        '.then((caches) => Toaster.postMessage(caches))');
  }

  void _onClearCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.clearCache();
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text("Cache cleared."),
    ));
  }

  void _onClearCookies(BuildContext context) async {
    final bool hadCookies = await cookieManager.clearCookies();
    String message = 'There were cookies. Now, they are gone!';
    if (!hadCookies) {
      message = 'There are no cookies.';
    }
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
    ));
  }

  void _onNavigationDelegateExample(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String contentBase64 =
    base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(kNavigationExamplePage));
    controller.loadUrl('data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64');
  }

  Widget _getCookieList(String cookies) {
    if (cookies == null || cookies == '""') {
      return Container();
    }
    final List<String> cookieList = cookies.split(';');
    final Iterable<Text> cookieWidgets =
    cookieList.map((String cookie) => Text(cookie));
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: cookieWidgets.toList(),
    );
  }
}



class NavigationControls extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationControls(this._webViewControllerFuture)
      : assert(_webViewControllerFuture != null);

  final Future<WebViewController> _webViewControllerFuture;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: _webViewControllerFuture,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
        final bool webViewReady =
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
        final WebViewController controller = snapshot.data;
        controllerGlobal = controller;

        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                if (await controller.canGoBack()) {
                  controller.goBack();
                } else {
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
                  );
                  return;
                }
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                if (await controller.canGoForward()) {
                  controller.goForward();
                } else {
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                        content: Text("No forward history item")),
                  );
                  return;
                }
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.replay),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () {
                controller.reload();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work if using Navigator 2.0 / go_router package etc as new navigation uses popRoute rather than WillPopScope for the back button handling. So you'll see it just about start to change the webview but then you will be navigated away from the page entirely